# Surface that refracts all rays onto a single point

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

I am trying to find the equation to the interface separating two optically different medium which will focus all rays coming from a point B(b,0) in medium 2 **($\mu$=m)** to a single point A(a,0) in medium 1 **($\mu$=n)** using the principle of least time.

I found the equation for the time it takes the rays to reach from B to A,
$$\left(\frac{n}{c}\right)\left(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}\right)+\left(\frac{m}{c}\right)\left(\sqrt{(x-b)^2+y^2}\right)$$

Now, according to POLT, this expression should be equal to something that is independent of the coordinates of the point (i.e. x and y) as it should be equal for all points on the interface for light to follow these paths.

Now i am pretty much stuck at finding the equation relating y to x for the surface.I tried differentiating this equation and setting that to zero since the other side is independent of x and is a constant but that became too complex to solve.

I need help in solving this equation for **y(x)**

The following image is an arbitrary visualization of such an interface **(m>n)**

[image: Interface Graph]

Comment: Can you include a drawing of the problem, with the points and axes labeled?  Note that the time cannot be independent of the positions of the two points B and A. Rather, it should be independent of the point where a ray intersects the interface.  In other words, represent the interface shape as a function of, e.g., x' and y', and show that time is independent of x'.

Comment: Yes that is what i mean. The points have coordinates (a,0) and (b,0) and the coordinates of an arbitrary point on the surface are (x,y) and thus when i say independent of x i mean independent of where the ray intersects the surface!
I am aware of the fact that the answer will be dependent on a and b.

Comment: What you are trying to do is to show that the lens maker’s formula is valid for a curved surface $x^2+y^2=R^2$ where $R$ is the radius of the surface.

Comment: @Farcher
I dont understand what you are trying to say
The equation i obtained for the time was by dividing the distances in respective media by the corresponding speed of light
I used simple distance formula to find the distance

Comment: What you are doing is trying to make all rays emerging from source $B$ to tke exactly the same time (ie arrive in phase) to reach point $A$.  If you Google something like  "Fermat lens equation" you will gets sites like http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~wilkins/optics/Lectures/Fermat.html where the assumption is that the surface is spherical and the lens equation is derived.

Comment: @Farcher Okaay thankyou!
But is my approach then wrong? Or another way that will result in getting the same answer?
I got the inspiration from Feynman Lectures On Physics Vol 1, the chapter on Geometrical Optics
http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_27.html
In this he says that the answer to this problem is a complex fourth degree curve and so i am skeptical about the spherical surface assumption

Comment: The time it takes can be computed for y= 0.  Does that help?

Comment: ... And the interface will have to be both continuous, and obeying the law of refraction, so for any given x,y , the angle of incidence is the vector of the incoming ray to the normal on the first derivative of the interface- equation. So thats another restraint.

Comment: @bukwyrm How do you propose we compute the time it takes for y=0 without knowing the x intercept? Because to get the x intercept we would have to plug in y=0 in the equation and set it equal to something, that something being the time of travel itself!
As to your next suggestion, i think the Snell's laws of refraction that you refer to here are infact a consequence of the principle of least time, and having already considered POLT, adding the laws of refraction as a constraint would hardly make a difference...

Comment: @ Rutwik : There should be such a surface for every x at y=0, so we'd just pick one.

Comment: @bukwyrm Yes that is what Roger suggested in his answer. That might certainly work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The closed curve for parameter values as shown in the Figure.

[image]

Not all curves for various values of $\:k\:$ correspond to acceptable solutions. In the second Figure above the blue curves are acceptable but the green curves must be rejected as "pushing" point $\:\rm A\:$ into medium 2.

---

**Proof that accepted curves obey Snell's law :**

\begin{equation}
n_{1}\sqrt{(x\!-\!a)^{2}+y^{2}}+n_{2}\sqrt{(x\!-\!b)^{2}+y^{2}}=k=ct_{\rm AB}=\text{constant} \qquad \Longrightarrow 
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm d \left[n_{1}\sqrt{(x\!-\!a)^{2}+y^{2}}+n_{2}\sqrt{(x\!-\!b)^{2}+y^{2}}\right]=\mathrm d k=0 \qquad \Longrightarrow 
\nonumber
\end{equation}

<sup>\begin{equation} 
n_{1}\left[\dfrac{(x\!-\!a)}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!a)^{2}+y^{2}}}\mathrm d x +\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!a)^{2}+y^{2}}}\mathrm d y\right]+n_{2}\left[\dfrac{(x\!-\!b)}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!b)^{2}+y^{2}}}\mathrm d x +\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!b)^{2}+y^{2}}}\mathrm d y\right]=0 
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\qquad =\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow \hphantom{===================================================} 
\nonumber
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation} 
n_{1}\left[\dfrac{(x\!-\!a)}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!a)^{2}+y^{2}}} +\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!a)^{2}+y^{2}}}\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right]+n_{2}\left[\dfrac{(x\!-\!b)}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!b)^{2}+y^{2}}}+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{(x\!-\!b)^{2}+y^{2}}}\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right]=0 
\nonumber
\end{equation}</sup>
 
\begin{equation} 
\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad n_{1}\left(\cos\omega_{1}  +\sin\omega_{1}\tan\phi\right)+n_{2}\left(-\cos\omega_{2}  +\sin\omega_{2}\tan\phi\right)=0 
\nonumber
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation} 
\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad n_{1}\left(\cos\omega_{1}\cos\phi +\sin\omega_{1}\sin\phi\right)-n_{2}\left(\cos\omega_{2}\cos\phi  -\sin\omega_{2}\sin\phi\right)=0 
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  
\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad n_{1}\cos\left(\phi-\omega_{1}\right) -n_{2}\cos\left(\phi+\omega_{2}\right)=0  
\nonumber
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}  
\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad n_{1}\sin\underbrace{\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\left(\phi-\omega_{1}\right)\right]}_{\theta_{1}} -n_{2}\sin\underbrace{\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\left(\phi+\omega_{2}\right)\right]}_{\theta_{2}}=0  
\nonumber
\end{equation}
that is 
\begin{equation}  
 n_{1}\sin\theta_{1} =n_{2}\sin\theta_{2} \qquad \textbf{(Snell's law)} 
\nonumber
\end{equation}

[image]

$===================================================$

[image]

Comment: I set the constraint that the curve must pass through some arbitrary point (p,q) and equated those two equations and got the exact same curve
Which is pretty much similar i guess to introducing a parameter k

Comment: @Rutwik  I hope that I help you a little, but really I must apologize to RogerJBarlow who is giving now and will give in the future amazing answers. We need all of us his experience.

Comment: Yes i mean him no disrespect too!
I accepted your answer just because i found it a bit better..

Comment: In thebsnells law graph, the blue curve is horizontal somewhere between x=10 and 11 . As this point is much nearer to B than to A, reflection cannot work, and as it is horizontal at y!=0, it cannot have a tangent from A. What happens to the light there (and probably more points along the curve (where do they start?))?

Comment: @bukwyrm The blue closed curve is a mathematical one. It's separated in two parts. One open part to the left defined by its two tangents from A ($\omega_{1_{max}}$), on which we have refraction, and a second open part to the right on which it's impossible a light ray from A to incident on.

Comment: From what tool are those graphs? I'm curious about some aspects (like what the tangent -points do on all the other curves, (i.e. what's the curve that offers maximum spread for rays from A to still reach B), but many more, and i'm wondering with what graphic-interface tool to pursue those questions - Geogebra?

Comment: @bukwyrm Precisely, GeoGebra.  It has a powerful command : The ImplicitCurve. See an image uploaded for you here [GeoGebra-ImplicitCurve](https://imgur.com/a/0yq5E83)

Answer (score 3):

Take your expression and set it equal to some constant $C$.
Square both sides to get $$\left({n \over c}\right)^2 \left( (x-a)^2+y^2 \right)+\left({m \over c}\right)^2 \left( (x-b)^2+y^2 \right)+
2\left({nm \over c^2}\right)^2\sqrt{ \left( (x-a)^2+y^2 \right)}
\sqrt{  \left( (x-b)^2+y^2 \right)}=C^2$$
Rearrange
 $$\left({n \over c}\right)^2 \left( (x-a)^2+y^2 \right)+\left({m \over c}\right)^2 \left( (x-b)^2+y^2 \right)-C^2=
2\left({nm \over c^2}\right)^2\sqrt{ \left( (x-a)^2+y^2 \right)}
\sqrt{  \left( (x-b)^2+y^2 \right)}$$
Square both sides again to get rid of all the square root signs and collect terms. I'll let you do the hard work. This is technically a quartic but there are terms in $y^4$, $y^2$ and $y^0$ so this actually gives you a quadratic equation for $y^2$ in terms of $x,n,m,a,b$ and $C$, which is what you want. Then $y=\pm\sqrt{y^2}$ which gives you the obvious symmetry of the shape about the $y=0$ axis.

The solution is not unique, it depends on $C$. You can choose the point at which the curve crosses the axis.

Comment: Yes i thought of solving it this way earlier. But as you said, it introduces an unnecessary constant into the equation. Is there no other way of solving it? Perhaps one that doesn't require the introduction of the constant C?

Comment: It's not unnecessary. The curve you are looking for is not unique. You have to break the ambiguity somehow.

Comment: Ohh okaay got it thankyou!
Also, is there any definite way to tell beforehand whether a given curve will be unique or not?